# Powershell Script to search for credit card numbers in a folder

Tags: powershell

I am using the below script to search for credit card numbers inside a folder that contains many subfolders:

```
Get-ChildItem  -rec | ?{ findstr.exe /mprc:. $_.FullName } 
    | select-string "[456][0-9]{15}","[456][0-9]{3}[-| ][0-9]{4} [-| ][0-9]{4}[-| ][0-9]{4}"
```

However, this will return all instances found in every folder/subfolder.

How can I amend the script to skip the current folder on the first instance found? meaning that if it finds a credit card number it will stop processing the current folder and move to the next folder.

Appreciate you answers and help.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: @Matt No, that's a regex. I think he's using it to filter out directories or zero-length files.

Comment: @BaconBits I see the /r that I missed now. You would need to loop for every folder and build an exit strategy with a boolean possibly

Answer (score 2):

You could use this recursive function:

```powershell
function cards ($dir)
  Get-ChildItem -Directory $dir | % { cards($_.FullName) }
  Get-ChildItem -File $dir\* | % {
    if ( Select-String $_.FullName "[456][0-9]{15}","[456][0-9]{3}[-| ][0-9]{4} [-| ][0-9]{4}[-| ][0-9]{4}" ) {
      write-host "card found in $dir"
      return
    }
  }
}

cards "C:\path\to\base\dir"
```

It'll keep going through subdirectories of the top level directory you specify. Whenever it gets to a directory with no subdirectories, or its been through all the subdirectories of the current directory, it'll start looking through the files for the matching regex, but will bail out of the function when the first match is found.

Answer (score 1):

So really what you want is the first file in every folder that has a credit card number in the contents.

Break it into two parts.  Get a list of all your folders, recursively.  Then, for each folder, get the list of files, non-recursively.  Search each file until you find one that matches.

I don't see any easy way to do this with pipes alone.  That means more traditional programming techniques.

This requires PowerShell 3.0.  I've eliminated `?{ findstr.exe /mprc:. $_.FullName }` because all I can see that it does is eliminate folders (and zero length files) and this already handles that.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $Found = $false;
    $i = 0;

    $Files = $_ | Get-ChildItem -File | Sort-Object -Property Name;

    for ($i = 0; ($Files[$i] -ne $null) -and ($Found -eq $false); $i++) {
        $SearchResult = $Files[$i] | Select-String "[456][0-9]{15}","[456][0-9]{3}[-| ][0-9]{4} [-| ][0-9]{4}[-| ][0-9]{4}";
        if ($SearchResult) {
            $Found = $true;
            Write-Output $SearchResult;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't have the time to test it fully, but I thought about something like this:

```
$Location = 'H:\'

$Dirs = Get-ChildItem $Location -Directory -Recurse
$Regex1 = "[456][0-9]{3}[-| ][0-9]{4} [-| ][0-9]{4}[-| ][0-9]{4}"
$Regex2 = "[456][0-9]{15}"

Foreach ($d in $Dirs) {

    $Files = Get-ChildItem $d.FullName -File

    foreach ($f in $Files) {
        if (($f.Name -match $Regex1) -or ($f.Name -match $Regex2)) {
            Write-Host 'Match found'
            Return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one, why not, the more the merrier.

I'm assuming that your Regex is correct.

Using `break` in the second loop will skip looking for a credit card in the remaining files if one is found and continue to the next folder.

```
$path = '<your path here>'
$folders = Get-ChildItem $path -Directory -rec  

foreach ($folder in $folders)
{ 
    $items = Get-ChildItem $folder.fullname -File

    foreach ($i in $items)
    {
        if (($found = $i.FullName| select-string "[456][0-9]{15}","[456][0-9]{3}[-| ][0-9]{4} [-| ][0-9]{4}[-| ][0-9]{4}") -ne $null)
        {
            break   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the intention was to look inside each file for the PII data right?

If so, you need to open the load the file and search each line. The code you posted will only run a regex on the name of the file.